# Incorrect file interpretation/ population

Tags: java, file, binary

I have just learned how to code and I am trying to create an application with signup and login functions. The code below adds the username and password to a text file which is working fine.

However, when I then try to login with the username and password the `verifyLogin` method is not working. If I manually add the password and username to the text file, then it will work fine. My best guess is that there is some conversion error but I am not sure.

This is the code to add the username and password to the file:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    String user = User.getSelectedItem().toString();
    String username = Username.getText();
    String password = Password.getText();
    String passwordConfirm = Password2.getText();

    if (user.trim().isEmpty() ||password.trim().isEmpty() || passwordConfirm.trim().isEmpty()){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Please fill out all fields");
    }
    else if(User.getSelectedItem().equals("Please Select")){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Please select wether you are a student ot a teacher");
    }
    else if(!password.equals(passwordConfirm)){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Please ensure the passwords you enter match");
    }
    else{
        if(User.getSelectedItem().equals("Student")){
            try{
                FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("Students.txt", true);
                writer.write(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                writer.write(username);
                writer.write(",");
                writer.write(password);
                writer.close();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Success. You now have a students account");
                MainGUI  x = new MainGUI();
                x.setVisible(true);
                this.dispose();
            }
            catch(HeadlessException | IOException e){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Error");
            }
        }
        else{
            try{
                FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("Teachers.txt", true);
                writer.write(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                writer.write(username);
                writer.write(",");
                writer.write(password);
                writer.close();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Success. You now have a teacher account");
                MainGUI  x = new MainGUI();
                x.setVisible(true);
                this.dispose();
            }
            catch(HeadlessException | IOException e){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Error");
            }  
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code to the teachers login:

```
public static void verifyLogin(String username, String password){
    boolean found = false;
    String tempUsername = "";
    String tempPassword = "";

    java.io.File file = new java.io.File("Teachers.txt");
    try{
        Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
        input.useDelimiter("[,\n]");

        while(input.hasNext() && !found){
            tempUsername = input.next();
            tempPassword = input.next();

            if (tempUsername.trim().equals(username.trim()) && tempPassword.trim().equals(password.trim())){
                found = true;
                TeacherOption  x = new TeacherOption();
                x.setVisible(true);
                this.dispose();
            }
            else{
                TeacherLoginError  x = new TeacherLoginError();
                x.setVisible(true);
                this.dispose();
            }
        }
        input.close();

    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        System.err.format("File does not exist \n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you look at the file after your code wrote the password to it? Does it look like you want it to, especially if you display the whitespace characters? One of the problems is that when writing you're using `line.separator` and when reading you assume the line separator is `\n`. Note those might not be the same thing and hence your delimiters might not work correctly, i.e. windows normally has `\r\n` as a line separator and thus your passwords might end in `\r`. (Btw, please be aware that doing it like this is highly unsecure so just use this for exercises.)

Comment: Just checked and `trim()` should get rid of that `\r` (carriage return) for you. Did you step through your code with a debugger (e.g. when running it directly from your IDE) and check the values being read from the file?

Comment: @Thomas trim() gets rid of the \r, but it doesn't prevent the \r from having the first line taken as a token. Though I guess there may be other problems. Should really read the file line-by-line and use a split() to separate username and password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a *newline* in the start of the file causing the trouble. Assume you are entering 3 `username` and `password`,

```
//empty line
Test1,TestPass1
Test2,TestPass2
Test3,TestPass3
```

Your data is read like this in the scanner,

```
user-1:

pass-1:Test1
user-2:TestPass1

pass-2:Test2
user-3:TestPass1

pass-3:Test3
user-4:TestPass3

pass-4:Test4
user-5:TestPass4
pass-5:
```

Hence causing the trouble.

**Below change should solve your problem,**

```
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("Students.txt", true);
writer.write(username);
writer.write(",");
writer.write(password);
writer.write(System.getProperty("line.separator"));//add the new line after writing your user credentials
writer.close();
```

Also I suggest to read the data per line (to avoid logical error and a cleaner pickup of data) and try storing the *password* in an encrypted format.

```
input.useDelimiter("\n");//take input per line
while(input.hasNext() && !found){
    String userDetails=input.next().trim();
    String credentialInfo[]=userDetails.split(",");
    if(!userDetails.isEmpty() 
            && credentialInfo.length==2) {//validate your input
        tempUsername = credentialInfo[0];
        tempPassword = credentialInfo[1];
        if (tempUsername.trim().equals(username.trim()) 
                && tempPassword.trim().equals(password.trim())){
              //rest of your code...
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had another look at your code and I can't believe I didn't see this: in your while loop you are displaying `TeacherLoginError` whenever a set of username and password doesn't match the input.

The problem? If you have a set that doesn't match before one that matches (which is the more common case) you'll display the error even if a later iteration would find the correct set. So first iterate and look for a username and password that matches and *after* the loop you decide what to show based on whether you found something or not.

What I mean is this:

Let's assume your file contains the following:

```
user1,password1
user2,password2
```

Now I enter "user2" and "password2". Your code (we assume it reads the data correctly) first checks this against `user1,password1` and since it doesn't match, you call the else-branch:

```
TeacherLoginError  x = new TeacherLoginError();
x.setVisible(true);
this.dispose();
```

What you need to do instead (reusing your code):

```
//first look for a match only
boolean found = false;
while(input.hasNext() && !found){
  tempUsername = input.next();
  tempPassword = input.next();

  if (tempUsername.trim().equals(username.trim()) && tempPassword.trim().equals(password.trim())){
     found = true;
     break; //end the loop, you've already found a match
  }
}

//after the loop you act based on whether you found a match or not
if(found) {
  TeacherOption  x = new TeacherOption();
  x.setVisible(true);
} else {
  TeacherLoginError  x = new TeacherLoginError();
  x.setVisible(true);
}

this.dispose(); //this is called anyways so no need to have it twice
```